# Site loads on Other Browsers but not Android Webview

Tags: android, http, webview

I have a simple, static personal test site with a proper TLS certificate. Both Chrome and Firefox on Windows, Linux and Android load this site normally.

However in Android Webview it doesn't load for some odd reason. It simply shows a blank screen, not even an error message. This is the code, very basic.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final WebView mainWv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWv);
        mainWv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mainWv.loadUrl("https://test.mysite.com:443/");
    }
}
```

### Interesting observations:

In fact this code doesn't even send a request to my server, which is just bizzare. (I have access to server console, which shows no requests.)

---

### What I already did/tried:

Internet permission has been added to manifest.

Using `WebChromeClient` gives the same result.

Loading via IP directly gives the same result.

Loading without port gives the same result.

Loading other sites works fine, e.g. `mainWv.loadUrl("https://google.com/");`.

---

This problem is so weird that I haven't the faintest clue where to even start debugging. Please help. Also I would like to know if you have success in other physical locations. Server is located in San Jose.

---

Webview running on Emulated Android 9 (API 28) and Google Pixel 3a Android 10 (API 29)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add the internet permission in your manifest? if not add the following line.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Replace the code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webview_compontent);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewController());
        webView.loadUrl("https://test.mysite.com");



    }
    public class WebViewController extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, final SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage("Error");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    handler.proceed();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    handler.cancel();
                }
            });
            final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }

    }

}
```